# How does kafka check for URP

Tags: apache-kafka

In kafka, we have one leader in n replicas and other replicate the data coming in from producer and the data across n replicas is maintained.

1. How does kafka check for URPs ?
2. Will there always be a lag in replicas if the data is constantly pushed in kafka consumer.

Answer (score 0):

The leader partition, the cluster controller and (currently) zookeeper coordinate in monitoring when brokers have matching high watermarks (all replicas are in sync). If they are not in sync, and less than `min.insync.replicas` config for the topic, then there are URPs.

Consumers don't push data, therefore lag doesn't increase because of them

Comment: So, is there is a minimum threshold which is considered ehen checking replicas ?
i am assuming that since data is replicated, there will always be a lag in data write acros replicas

Comment: Are you referring to the `min.insync.replicas` setting?